# SQL Server 2008: Update/Insert data(multiple records) from multiple columns of different tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-update, multiple-columns, sql-insert

I have to write a procedure to update table if record exists, else insert the data. I am getting records from different columns as comma-separated strings.
For example: 
ID = "2,3,4,5"; 
Names = "S,D,G,H"; 
Approach that I have taken is: Created ID Table and Names Table with single column each. (Split function being used, returns table with single column which contains values). And then I am trying to insert/update the data. Insert is working fine. But for Update record, it's updating with incorrect values. 
I am new to SQL and just can't get around with what am I doing wrong or if my approach is fine! Please help. Kindly note, in my approach I have used row_num to pick records in correct order from different temp tables. Following is my code: 

Table Design:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestMultipleInsert](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Number] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Number1] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TestMultipleInsert] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Code for Update/Insert

```
declare @names table (name varchar(50));  --Consider as split string values of Name Column
declare @numbers table (phone int); -- Consider as split string values of Number column
declare @number1s table (phone1 int); -- Consider as split string values of Number1 column
declare @MCodes table (Id int); --Consider as split string values of Id column. If Id = -1, then it's a new entry, else updated record.


-- Insert test data for running query
insert into @names (name) values('First');
insert into @names (name) values('Second');
insert into @names (name) values('Third');
insert into @names (name) values('Fourth');

insert into @numbers (phone) values(112);
insert into @numbers (phone) values(399);
insert into @numbers (phone) values(499);
insert into @numbers (phone) values(499);

insert into @number1s (phone1) values(112);
insert into @number1s (phone1) values(299);
insert into @number1s (phone1) values(399);
insert into @number1s (phone1) values(399);

insert into @MCodes (Id) values(54); --Update
insert into @MCodes (Id) values(-1); --Insert
insert into @MCodes (Id) values(50); --Update
insert into @MCodes (Id) values(-1); --Insert

--Query
insert into dbo.TestMultipleInsert (Name, Number, Number1)
select A.name, B.phone, C.phone1
from(
    SELECT name,row_number() over (order by (select 0)) as row_num
    FROM @names)A,
    (SELECT phone,row_number() over (order by (select 0)) as row_num
    FROM @numbers)B,
    (SELECT phone1,row_number() over (order by (select 0)) as row_num
    FROM @number1s)C,
    (SELECT Id,row_number() over (order by (select 0)) as row_num
    FROM @MCodes)D
where  A.row_num=B.row_num  and A.row_num = C.row_num  and D.row_num = A.row_num and D.Id = -1

Update dbo.TestMultipleInsert 
SET Name=A.Name, Number =B.phone, Number1= C.phone1
from(
    SELECT name,row_number() over (order by (select 0)) as row_num
    FROM @names)A,
    (SELECT phone,row_number() over (order by (select 0)) as row_num
    FROM @numbers)B,
    (SELECT phone1,row_number() over (order by (select 0)) as row_num
    FROM @number1s)C,
(SELECT Id,row_number() over (order by (select 0)) as row_num
    FROM @MCodes)D
    where  D.row_num=B.row_num  and D.row_num = C.row_num  and D.row_num = A.row_num and D.Id <> -1 and D.Id = dbo.TestMultipleInsert.Id

select * from dbo.TestMultipleInsert;
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A1) I don't know what your big picture is, but your script is working as far as I can tell.  The INSERT is inserting what I expect, and the UPDATE is updating the records that I expect. There's nothing technically wrong with using the row_number() over() function, but it's a little more straight-forward with the way I suggest below. (just preference in this situation)

Assuming you must have the four separate tables (temp tables), here is one way to do it.  I added auto increment primary keys to the table variables to make joining the data more straight-forward.

You could also use a MERGE statement to do both the update and insert in one go. (About MERGE: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625(v=sql.105).aspx)

```
--added auto increment primary key to avoid using window function row_nmber() over()...
declare @names table (pkey int primary key identity,name varchar(50));  --Consider as split string values of Name Column
declare @numbers table (pkey int primary key identity, phone int); -- Consider as split string values of Numer column
declare @number1s table (pkey int primary key identity, phone1 int); -- Consider as split string values of Number1 column
declare @MCodes table (pkey int primary key identity,Id int); --Consider as split string values of Id column. If Id = -1, then it's a new entry, else updated record.


-- Insert test data for running query
insert into @names (name) values('First');
insert into @names (name) values('Second');
insert into @names (name) values('Third');
insert into @names (name) values('Fourth');

insert into @numbers (phone) values(112);
insert into @numbers (phone) values(399);
insert into @numbers (phone) values(499);
insert into @numbers (phone) values(499);

insert into @number1s (phone1) values(112);
insert into @number1s (phone1) values(299);
insert into @number1s (phone1) values(399);
insert into @number1s (phone1) values(399);

insert into @MCodes (Id) values(54);
insert into @MCodes (Id) values(-1);
insert into @MCodes (Id) values(50);
insert into @MCodes (Id) values(-1);

--Insert Query
INSERT INTO dbo.TestMultipleInsert (Name, Number, Number1)
SELECT A.name, B.phone, C.phone1
FROM @names A
    JOIN @numbers B ON B.pkey = A.pkey
    JOIN @number1s C ON C.pkey = A.pkey
    JOIN @MCodes D ON D.pkey = A.pkey
WHERE D.Id = -1

--Update query
UPDATE dbo.TestMultipleInsert 
SET Name = upd.Name
  , Number = upd.phone
  , Number1 = upd.phone1
FROM(
    SELECT A.name, B.phone, C.phone1, D.Id
    FROM @names A
        JOIN @numbers B on B.pkey = A.pkey
        JOIN @number1s C on C.pkey = A.pkey
        JOIN @MCodes D on D.pkey = A.pkey
    WHERE D.Id <> -1
    ) upd
WHERE upd.Id = dbo.TestMultipleInsert.Id
```

A2) If you need to get a list of the identity values for an insert, declare a table variable (to get rows for all IDs) like this before your script that inserts:

```
DECLARE @myIDs table (ID int);
```

Then use the OUTPUT clause with your insert statement (if ID is your key column):

```
INSERT INTO tableBlah
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID INTO @myIDs
VALUES ...blah blah
```

You can then join your other queries (update, select etc) to the table variable to find the records that were just inserted.

Comment: How can I get the generated identity values for all the rows inserted?

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't able to update the records using row_num. I am facing another issue after this. Could you please look at [follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35336715/5901171) and suggest something? Thanks