# SQL Server 2008: Sql Insert/Update into another table using insertion IDs output from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, sql-insert, insert-into

I have a procedure for insert in multiple dependent tables (update in case record exist). I have input parameters as comma separated string which I am reading in table.

After 1st insertion I am getting InsertedIds in another table variable.
I am struggling over how to do insert in 2nd table. I have following input parameters for 2nd table:

```
Declare @IdsToBeUpdated table (primary key identity pkey, id int) -- values are 1,-1,3,-1
Declare @CommentsTobeInserted table( primary key identity pkey, comment varchar (max)) -- values are 'com1', 'com2', 'com3'
```

-1 input in table `@IdsToBeUpdated` depicts insertion for the corresponding rows in all input tables and value other than -1 depicts that records at that pkey value in all other tables (`@CommentsTobeInserted` table as in example) have to be updated.

So after first insertion I am getting the inserted ids for rows with -1 value. @InsertedIds = 4,5

So my Ids list logically would become.. 1,4,3,5.

But I am stuck now how to insert/update records in second table respectively.
2nd table would be like follows:

```
Pkey Primary key identity, commentIds(coming from inserted ids and @IdsToBeUpdated), comments.
```

I have added one more InsertedIds column in @CommentsTobeInserted. If I could fill it with right InsertedId against correct row, I guess I would be able to do insert/update in 2nd table. And where the value is Id in new column I would do insert, where it's null, I would perform update using @IdsToBeUpdated table.
But currently none of my approach is working. I am new to SQL. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Following is some portion of script for better understanding. I have added first insertion script as well.

```
USE [Demo]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[USP_NewRequest_Insert]    Script Date: 2/11/2016 2:50:34 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_NewRequest_Insert] 
-----------------------------------
--------- SomeInput parameters
---------for first insertion omitted
--------------------------------            
 @IdsToBeUpdated varchar(MAX),  --Values are 23|-1|32|-1|-1
@CommentList AS VARCHAR(MAX),   --Values 'C2'|'C4'|'C5'|'C6'|'C7'     
  @MCodeList VARCHAR(MAX),      --Values  'M2'|'M4'|'M5'|'M6'|'M7' 
 @CustomerIdsList VARCHAR(MAX), ----Values  'Cust2'|'Cust4'|'Cust5'|'Cust6'|'Cust7' 
 @ReturnValue  AS INT OUTPUT,            
 ------------------Data is in the order it has to be inserted.. where IDs exist in @IdsToBeUpdated, updation would be done. For -1 values, insertion.
 AS            
BEGIN          

 BEGIN TRANSACTION         
 --------------------------Split input strings aand insert in Table variable----------------------------
  declare @MCodes Table (pkey int primary key identity, MCode varchar(20))
      insert into @MCodes select s.Item from [dbo].UDF_SplitString(@MCodeList, '|') s

      declare @CusCodes Table (pkey int primary key identity, CusCode varchar(200))
      insert into @CusCodes select s.Item from [dbo].UDF_SplitString(@CustomerIdsList, '|') s

      declare @ReqDetailsIds Table (pkey int primary key identity, Id Int)
      insert into @ReqDetailsIds select Convert(INT,RTRIM(LTRIM(s.Item))) from [dbo].UDF_SplitString(@IdsToBeUpdated, '|') s
where s.Item is not null and RTRIM(LTRIM(s.Item)) <>''

      declare @ProductComments Table (pkey int primary key identity, Comment Varchar(max), insertedId int null)
      insert into @ProductComments(Comment) select s.Item from [dbo].UDF_SplitString(@CommentList, '|') s
DECLARE @intErrorCode int;

 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 -----------------First Insertion which returns inserted IDs for 2nd insertion
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---Insert/Update product details in [RequestDetails]        
  Declare @InsertedIDList Table (pkey int primary key identity, ID int);  --------Table to read inserted Ids. Used in query below
-----------------------Insert query in case Detail id = -1
  INSERT INTO [dbo].[RequestDetails]
            [MCode]
           ,[CustomerIds]
           ,[ExpectedVolume]------Some parameters coming for first insertion in input
           ,[StatusCode])
           Output INSERTED.ReqDetailId Into @InsertedIDList(ID)
SELECT A.MCode, B.CusCode, E.Vol,1
FROM @MCodes A
    JOIN @CusCodes B ON B.pkey = A.pkey
    JOIN @ExpectedVols E ON E.pkey = A.pkey
    JOIN @ReqDetailsIds G ON G.pkey = A.pkey
WHERE G.Id = -1           --If id = -1, insert

 ---------------------------Update Query for rest records
UPDATE [dbo].[RequestDetails]
   SET [MCode] = upd.MCode
      ,[CustomerIds] = upd.CusCode
      ,[ExpectedVolume] = upd.ExVol
      ,[StatusCode] = 1
FROM(
    SELECT A.MCode, B.CusCode, E.ExVol, G.Id
FROM @MCodes A
    JOIN @CusCodes B ON B.pkey = A.pkey
    JOIN @ExpectedVols E ON E.pkey = A.pkey
    JOIN @ReqDetailsIds G ON G.pkey = A.pkey
    WHERE G.Id <> -1
    ) upd
WHERE upd.Id = dbo.RequestDetails.ReqDetailId

 IF(@@Error<>0)          
  BEGIN    
  SET @intErrorCode = @@Error            
   GOTO ERROR          
   END            
  ELSE            
  BEGIN            
   SET @ReturnValue=1            
  END            


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------Now similarly I have to do insert/update in Comments Table. But
----------------------------Comments table has RequestDetails Id column as foreign key. So 
----------------------------now the challange is to add the rows with Inserted ID where value was = -1 
----------------------------in input. We have got the IDs corresponding to -1 values from above insertion
----------------------------in the @InsertedIDList Table variable
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------Following is what I have tried so far. But I am not able to insert
----------------------------correct InsertedId against correct record.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


-----------------------Here I tried to insert the new generated ids against corresponding comments in table variable.
-----------------------So that I can perform insert where value is not null. As NULL would be inserted where new ID has not been created
-----------------------and corresponding updated ID exists in input (Values not equal to -1)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Update @ProductComments  set insertedId = i.ID from                                         ---------This query is not working
(select A.pkey, B.id as detailId, row_number() over (order by (select 0)) as row_num  from
@ProductComments A
    JOIN @ReqDetailsIds B ON B.pkey = A.pkey) as mappedNewIds right join
     @InsertedIDList i on i.pkey = mappedNewIds.row_num
     where  mappedNewIds.pkey = [@ProductComments].pkey

----Insert in CommentsTable for New Comments against request
---------------------------------
INSERT INTO [dbo].CommentsTable
            ( ReqDetailId, Comments, CreatedOn  )
SELECT  A.insertedId, A.Comment, GETDATE()
FROM @ProductComments A
    where A.insertedId is not null

-----Update Query
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
UPDATE [dbo].[CommentsTable]
   SET [ReqDetailId] = upd.Id
      ,[Comments] = upd.Comment
      ,[CreatedOn] = GetDate()
FROM(
    SELECT A.Comment, B.Id
FROM @ProductComments A
    JOIN @ReqDetailsIds B ON B.pkey = A.pkey
WHERE  A.insertedId is not null
    ) upd
WHERE upd.Id = dbo.CommentsTable.ReqDetailId

 END         

    select * from CommentsTable;

    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  IF(@@Error<>0)          
  BEGIN    
  SET @intErrorCode = @@Error            
   GOTO ERROR          
   END            
  ELSE            
  BEGIN            
   SET @ReturnValue=1            
  END            

 COMMIT TRANSACTION   

 ERROR:
IF (@intErrorCode <> 0) BEGIN
 SET @ReturnValue = 0; 
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION         
END
END
```

Comment: You should consider posting an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (a **M**inimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example). Your script is too long to wade through. Also condense your problem statement in fewer sentences/paragraphs, remove the information that has nothing to do with your problem. Read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).